# What are the best PDF and XLS reporting solutions on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: pdf, ruby

The solution I'm looking for is not using rail's view because I'm using rails only in Back end. I have an AngularJS front end. I'm trying PrawnPdf right now and I have some issues with performances when my report is over 500 pages. The solution doesn't have to be a freeware.

Comment: "The best" is much to opinion-based to be a stand-alone criterium. What features do you need? What's your budget? Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your post to incorporate some of those improvements. The better we can understand what you need, the better answers/recommendations can be matched to that. Thanks!